# Firefox, CSS display: table / table-cell and height

Tags: html, css, firefox

Im displaying several content in `div` and `span` elements in a table like style.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-col-glyphicon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove item-glyphicon"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="item-col1">
      <span class="item-col1-a">a</span>
      <span class="item-col1-b">b</span>
    </div>
    <div class="separator"></div>
    <div class="details">
      <span style="display:block">Line 1</span>
      <span style="display:block">Line 2</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `glyphicon-remove` should be vertically centered, which works fine in Chrome and IE 11 but not Firefox 52.

The expected result looks like this:

[image]

The Firefox result looks like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?
I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AlexZeitler/x1uydngo/).

Comment: maybe it has to do with icon and its container which are both displayed as table-cell ... https://jsfiddle.net/x1uydngo/10/

Comment: Thanks! This led me to the correct direction and here is the final result (I need to colorize the `separator` border different from it's body/background: https://jsfiddle.net/AlexZeitler/x1uydngo/13/ - also I added some width-values to the table-cell items according to my needs.

Comment: @GCyrillus please post your fiddle as answer so I can mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

the 0.7em on the class item-glyphicon was not required for mozilla. so i made that rule chrome specific. Heres the link to working fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/x1uydngo/9/

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
{ 
.item-glyphicon{top:0.7em;} 
}
```